# how to recursively fetch some data with pattern using wget

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to download some specific files from this website (http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hourly/prod/), they keep 10 days data. I want to download all the files starting with "ST4" from all the directories starting with "nam_pcpn_anal". I could download all the files staring with "ST4" from one folder like :

```
wget -r -nd -N --no-parent -nH --cut-dirs=100 -P ~/test/ -A ST4* 'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hourly/prod/nam_pcpn_anal.20160625/'
```

but I do not know how to search ST4 recursively. I thought the following should work but nope!

```
wget -r -nd -N --no-parent -nH --cut-dirs=100 -P ~/test/ -A ST4* --accept nam_pcpn_anal*/ST4* 'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hourly/prod/'
```

Any idea!

Comment: See also [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/), it has [filters](https://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wget` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) shows:

```
   -I list
   --include-directories=list
       Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to follow
       when downloading.  Elements of list may contain wildcards.
```

So, you could try:

```
wget -r -nd -N --no-parent -nH --cut-dirs=100 -P ~/test/ \
    -A 'ST4*' -I '*/nam_pcpn_anal.*' \
    'http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hourly/prod/'
```

Comment: Thanks, It should work. But I am afraid it does not.

Comment: What happens if you use `-I 'nam_pcpn_anal.*'` instead?

Comment: The same, I guess something is not right at my end with wget, otherwise the solution you post make sense and should work.